# Styling div from css file in multiple RMarkdown files

Tags: html, css, r, r-markdown

I am looking to use a css file to style divs in numerous RMarkdown files. I am having issues with the syntax to have the external css file style the div.

Using the style tag within the rmarkdown body works (code example below)

```
---
title: "Untitled"
output: 
  html_document
---

<style>
div.positive {
  background-color: #006B35;
  color: #ffffff; font-size:
  16px; text-align:left;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 0 10px;
  80px
}

div.negative {
  background-color: #C83C4D;
  color: #ffffff; font-size:
  16px; text-align:left;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 0 10px;
  80px
}
</style>

<div class="positive">
Green background div
</div>

<div class="negative">
Red background div
</div>
```

When I remove the in body style and reference a css file the divs are not styled (code example below)

**CSS**

```
.positive {
  background-color: #006B35;
  color: #ffffff; font-size:
  16px; text-align:left;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 0 10px;
  80px
}

.negative {
  background-color: #C83C4D;
  color: #ffffff; font-size:
  16px; text-align:left;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 0 10px;
  80px
}
```

**RMarkdown**

```
---
title: "Untitled"
output: 
  html_document:
  css: "style.css"
---

<style>
div.positive {

}

div.negative {

}
</style>


<div class="positive">
Green background div
</div>

<div class="negative">
Red background div
</div>
```

The purpose for using a single css file is to be able to change the style in a single file rather than in the body of multiple rmarkdown files.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: It works for me if I indent the `css:` line more than the `html_document:` line.

Comment: Thanks....such an easy fix and it works...much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The YAML header needs indentation that corresponds to the logical organization.  You had

```
---
title: "Untitled"
output: 
  html_document:
  css: "style.css"
---
```

but should have

```
---
title: "Untitled"
output: 
  html_document:
    css: "style.css"
---
```

with extra indentation for the `css:` line.